# Convert Non-zero value to one

Tags: opencv

In Matlab, I can use logical(img) to convert all non-zero element to one.

Is there a simple way(i.e. without loop) to convert all non-zero stored in cv::Mat to one in OpenCV?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to load a .mat file into openCV?

Comment: Sorry I mislead you. I mean cv::Mat.

Comment: I think you need to "hardcode" it with a couple of loops.

Comment: quick in terms of "simple/short code" or "fast processing"? which data type? float? uchar? int? double?

Comment: "Quick" in terms of lines of code to write? If so, use [OpenCV's threshold function](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There number of functions that may help you but that depends on what you have and what you are trying to get.

1) OpenCV has function [compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#compare) and operator '!=' (as well as any other operator you may need). You can write:

```
img = (img != 0);
```

This will convert any non-zero value of matrix to 255. I know that you wanted to convert it to 1, but if 255 is good enough for you than this is the best method. In any task I encountered in the past conversion to 255 was always better than conversion to 1, because you can use resulting image for all kinds of bitwise operations like logic AND, OR, etc...

2) If you do want to make conversion to 1, and your matrix is positive integers (or chars, or shorts), you can use function [min](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#min).

```
img = min(img,1);
```

3) Also you can use function [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) as @Roger Rowland suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `threshold()` function in OpenCV for convenience.
You mention "non-zero" elements. If your matrix has negative numbers, and you still want those to be set to 1, use `threshold( abs(my_mat), .. )`.

In general, this can also be done through this:

```
Mat my_mat;
Mat reference = Mat::zeros( rows, cols, type );

Mat result = (abs(my_mat) > reference)/255;
```

This is longer, and probably looks messier, but it has the advantage that `reference` can be adjusted to something other than all zeros if required (it could be a gradient, for example). Also, `<` is *not* the only operator that can fit there- any logical operator can be used. The result of a logical operation is always either 0 or 255, hence the division.